# How can we run a fastAPI application on two ports one HTTP and one HTTPS without redirecting?

Tags: ssl, https, gunicorn, fastapi

I want to host my `fastAPI` application using `gunicorn` and host it on a Kubernetes Service. My Kubernetes service runs a liveness probe (health check) using `HTTP` call on a specified endpoint.

I also want the application to be served on `HTTPS` because my Kubernetes service exposes it to be used by external components.

Now my HTTP endpoint can't rely on redirection as the liveness probe expects a `200 Response` and redirection will hamper that.

I want to host my HTTPS endpoint on a pre-specified port as the organization has the best practices in place and the endpoint and port are specified.

Some similar problems on StackOverflow:

1. [Running Gunicorn on both http and https](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35578989/running-gunicorn-on-both-http-and-https)
2. [uvicorn [fastapi] python run both HTTP and HTTPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69138537/uvicorn-fastapi-python-run-both-http-and-https)

But both of these are okay with redirection, and we are not. And we cannot use the `NGINX` server too, because that support is deprecated in my organization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we are trying this out in a Docker environment. The following will get it done:

Dockerfile:

```
ENTRYPOINT ./start.sh
```

Shell Script start.sh:

```
gunicorn -k uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker -w 3 -b 0.0.0.0:30000 -t 360 --reload app:app & gunicorn -k uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker -w 3 --ssl-certfile certfile.txt --ssl-keyfile keyfile.txt --ca-certs ca_certs.txt -b 0.0.0.0:8443 -t 360 --reload app:app
```

The `&` runs one in the background and then runs the other one. You can configure one to use HTTP and one to use HTTPS.

We are using `gunicorn` for `fastAPI` application so we are using `uvicorn` workers and you need to change it accordingly for your use case.

Answer (score 1):

For people landing here looking for fastapi/uvicorn help:

```py
uvicorn api:app\
 --ssl-certfile=yourcert.pem\
 --ssl-keyfile=yourkey.pem\
 --host 0.0.0.0 --port 443 --workers 1\
  &\
 uvicorn api:app\
 --host 0.0.0.0 --port 80 --workers 1
```

You should know, the background daemon will fail to close on `CTRL+C`. It's best to use something like tmux, and run the `:80` and `:443` in different windows.

Comment: Is there a way to run it a python script?